# Windows 10 UWP App Launch from Package List (FindPackage)

Tags: c#, uwp

My goal is to launch a file from an app that the user specifies in my UWP app. When I hit on the Launch button, I navigate backwards into my AppData (UWP) Packages folder, then I iterate through folder and utilize the PackageManager class to retrieve packages by name. I try to initialize a package with the right package name using FindPackage ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.findpackage?view=winrt-19041)). However, it doesn't work for me and I get an exception "Value does not fall within the expected range" when calling FindPackage.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
StorageFolder currApp = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
Debug.WriteLine(currApp.Path);

// move up and get parent folder for all packages
DirectoryInfo currAppFolder = Directory.GetParent(currApp.Path);

DirectoryInfo pkgs = Directory.GetParent(currAppFolder.FullName);
StorageFolder pkgFldr = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(pkgs.FullName);

var pkgDirs = await pkgFldr.GetFoldersAsync();

Package UwpPkg = null;
var PkgMgr = new PackageManager();

foreach (StorageFolder dir in pkgDirs)
{
        string folderName = dir.Name;

        var currPkg = PkgMgr.FindPackage(folderName);

        if (filter == currPkg.DisplayName)
        {
                // we found it
                UwpPkg = currPkg;
                break;
        }
}
```

I've also already configured necessary permissions (rescap: broadFileSystemAccess).

Did someone also have such problems/a possible solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Windows 10 UWP App Launch from Package List (FindPackage)

Please check [`PackageManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.findpackage?view=winrt-19041) document,  for this api it need `packageQuery` capability

```
<Package
xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap" >

......

 <rescap:Capability Name="packageQuery" />
```

And please note

*This method requires **administrative privileges**. The returned package may be installed for the current user or for another user*. So please invoke above in the elevated desktop extension. For more you could stefan's blog **App Elevation Samples**.

Comment: Yeah, packageQuery did it. Thank you!